# Should my header files be able to compile on their own?

Tags: c++, compilation, header-files

A colleague recently claimed that header files should always be able to compile on their own (e.g. calling `g++ someHeader.hpp` should result in `someHeader.hpp.gch` without failure).

Is this statement "true"?

Is it a good/common practice to check if your headers are able to compile on their own?

If yes, what would be the advantage of such a test?

To me, this seems counterintuitive, since headers are included by the preprocessor in the compilation unit and only have to compile in the context of that unit.

Comment: How could that fail? Did your colleague explain what it would mean to them?

Comment: Perhaps he/she meant that it's a good test to see that it includes all the header files it needs on it's own and isn't dependent on what the `.cpp` file includes?

Comment: I am not sure @Yunnosch

Comment: To expand on my previous comment: In theory a tool like [`include-what-you-use`](https://include-what-you-use.org/) should work to make sure you've included exactly what you need, nothing more and nothing less - but I haven't found one that does a really good job.

Comment: A header file should generally provide all declarations and macros, and also include other headers it depends on.  For example, if a source file includes header A, and that source file then always needs to include header B in order to compile, then header A should probably declare whatever is in header B (which may amount to simply including header B).  Checking if a header file compiles to a pre-compiled header may be one means to check if that is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good/common practice to check if your headers are able to compile on their own?

Yes. The practice is good and as far as I know, common.

> If yes, what would be the advantage

A header that doesn't work by itself must necessarily rely on the context where it is going to be included. 
Having a header work only when included into certain context is fragile. Fragility is a code smell.

> ... headers are included by the preprocessor in the compilation unit and only have to compile in the context of that unit.

... And also every other unit where the header is included into. Including those units that have not been written yet. And it should also keep working when changes are made to those units.

A header that only works in a single translation unit at one point in time is not a very useful header in the long term.